# List taxonomies name and related post wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops, categories

I use wordpress.
In my custom template with bootstrap, I would like to create a listing of taxomies and related posts under its own taxonomy, as in the image.

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'altri_prodotti', 
'posts_per_page' => -1
) );

 if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">

    <h2><?php echo get_the_terms( 'category' ); ?></h2>

   <article class="vu_menu-item clearfix">

   <a href="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">

<span class="vu_menu-item-img">

<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

</span>
```

```
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

     </article>
        </div> 

        <?php endwhile; ?>

      <?php endif;
     wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
```

[image]

Comment: where is your WordPress code? what have you tried?

Comment: I solved with this post ! It Work ! https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66219/list-all-posts-in-custom-post-type-by-taxonomy